# jQuery detect element under element being dragged on mouseenter/mouseleave

Tags: jquery, typescript

I've got a bit of an odd one here... I've got event listeners on both mouseenter and mouseleave events as below.

```
$(".dropContainer").on("mouseenter", dropContainerEnter);
$(".dropContainer").on("mouseleave", dropContainerLeave);
```

...but they only seem to fire when the cursor moves over the element attached with speed and both events seem to fire simultaneously (or not at all). js fiddle below with a demonstration of the issue (console.log on each eventfiring).

https://jsfiddle.net/1b68eLdr/5341/

Essentially you drag an element from the left (test 1/ test 2...) into the right hand div, I need to be able to detect the mouse enter and leave accordingly. Can anyone show me how to fix it?

UPDATE: So I've realised the reason this is happening is because I'm dragging an element and trying to detect when the mouse moves over a div, the reason it only works at all when the cursor is moving quickly is because the cursor briefly loses the element it's dragging and can therefore detect the div.

Is there any way to make the dynamically generated element (below) "transparent" so the mouseenter event detects the div and other elements underneath it instead?

```
$(".dragAndDropContainer").append("<p class='clone'>" + $(target).text() + "</p>");
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/1b68eLdr/5364/ Is this what you're looking for? It looks like you just had the mouseenter/mouseleave setup wrong and in the wrong spot.

Comment: Almost, I only want them to fire when an element is being dragged, hence the mouseenter/mouseleave setup within the mouseDown function and listener removal in the mouseUp function. 

Stragely enough I moved your changes back into the function and it worked once, can't get it to work again...

Comment: Got it! The setup was wrong and then had to unbind it differently. thanks for your help!

https://jsfiddle.net/1b68eLdr/5373/

Comment: Glad you got it working :)

Comment: thought I had, not quite... On the bright side I know what the problem is, just not how to fix it. Will update the question shortly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out the issue, figured i may as well post the answer on the off chance someone's had a similar issue. The original issue was that i was setting mouseenter/leave event listeners on a div and trying to detect that div while dragging another element.

The resolution was to add the below css to the element being dragged, a setting I'd never heard of till now.

```
pointer-events: none;
```